# Is this piece of flint a Native American tool?

Tags: united-states, history, manmade-object-identification

I was walking in a cornfield this afternoon.  It is located in the Midwestern United States.  I found this particularly interesting piece of flint.  It has a sharp edge all the way around. I don't think it is an arrow or spear head.  However, I find it hard to believe that this piece of flint would be sharp all the way around. Perhaps it was a small axe head?

Question : 
What is this piece of flint? Am I being too creative or is it a Native American artifact?
[image]

Comment: I have found similar things in the past and when asking local experts at the time i was told that sometimes a tool would be discarded after it was started if they did not like the way it was shaping up or noticed some sort of flaw that would make it weaker or prone to breaking. Don't know how much truth there is to that but that is what i was told. It indeed does look like it has been worked though and not totally natural.

Answer (score 3):

It does not appear to me to be naturally shaped; it looks like human hands fashioned it. I don't see any sign of notches for affixing to a staff so I agree not a spearhead, but it does look like what I've heard were used as skinning knives, to help separate skin from game.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Jimmy Fix-it, it doesn't appear to be naturally shaped.

I am certainly no expert on stone tools and it is a little hard to see from your images, but it looks a little like it has been [knapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapping) for shape and and looks like it has been pecked along the edges at least partially. It may be that it is an unfinished tool as it appears only partially worked, [but scrapers and hand choppers often appear unfinished](https://www.theclassroom.com/how-to-identify-the-stone-tools-of-native-americans-12084193.html). As you know where it was found, some things to consider about the object - are there other stones around that are similar? Is the type of stone one that is commonly/naturally found in your area?

Your best bet for identification is to take it along to your local museum and ask them about it.